# Diskless servers: why is my service script run after networking is set up?

Tags: systemd

Background: I am building a slurm cluster consisting of a master node and a number of compute nodes, which all start up via PXE. They do not have hostnames, initially, and since they may run on different HW, the names of NICs may not be predictible, so they are not configured, eg in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I set the hostname during boot like this:

```
root@zorn:/lib/systemd/system# cat /lib/systemd/system/sethostname.service
[Unit]
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
After=local-fs.target
DefaultDependencies=false

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sethostname
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

with /usr/bin/sethostname:

```
root@zorn:/lib/systemd/system# cat /usr/bin/sethostname
#!/usr/bin/bash

hnm=node$(/usr/bin/cat /sys/class/net/*/address | /usr/bin/head -1 | /usr/bin/sed 's/://g')
echo $hnm > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
echo $hnm > /etc/hostname
```

The root filesystem is mounted R/O via NFS, so `/etc/hostname` is a symbolic link to a file on a local disk.

So far, so good; when I start the diskless node, the hostname is set to something like `node6c2408faee43`:

```
root@node080027aea419:~# hostnamectl
 Static hostname: node080027aea419
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm 
      Machine ID: 17759b12ed8542b9a8600afa47bd017c
         Boot ID: ea43f2bd2b4f4887bba39adabcbaa44e
  Virtualization: oracle
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)  
          Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: innotek GmbH
  Hardware Model: VirtualBox
Firmware Version: VirtualBox
```

and the IP address has been set from DHCP, which has been configured with DDNS (which works for all other systems).

However, I can't see the hostname on the server - not in DNS, not in the logs or anywhere else. What do I need to add/change so that the hostname is communicated to the DHCP server?

***Edit***

I added a bit of debugging to the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/ip a > /var/ip.log
hnm=node$(/usr/bin/cat /sys/class/net/*/address | /usr/bin/head -1 | /usr/bin/sed 's/://g')
echo $hnm > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
echo $hnm > /etc/hostname
```

and after rebooting, `/var/ip.log` shows:

```
root@node080027aea419:~# cat /var/ip.log
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ae:a4:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.168/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So, the IP address has already been set, which explains why the hostname isn't sent to the DHCP server; but why? The way I've set it up, I would expect my script to be run before the interface has been configured.

Comment: Is there any `ip=` in the kernel parameters (in `/proc/cmdline`)? With PXE environment I'd expect something would have configured the node to get an IP address during boot (ie: during /boot/inird.img* phase if not directly by the kernel itself)?

Comment: @A.B You know, there is: `ip=dhcp`. Otherwise it wouldn't be able to mount its `nfsroot`. Hmm, a workaround might be to set the hostname after the network is ready and then refresh the lease. If you were to write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It's fine if you write it yourself. I'm not familiar enough with the integration (depends on the network tool in charge, of the dhcp backend to be used...)

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered, essentially, by @A.B in a comment, but I'll add it as an answer so it can be marked 'solved'.

The problem really stems from the fact that the system starts up with the root directory mounted read-only via NFS by the kernel; in order to do that, the kernel requests an IP address from the DHCP server, like this (from `grub.cfg`):

```
menuentry 'Debian 12' {
  set background_color=black
  linux /debian12/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-9-amd64 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs ro nfsroot=192.168.50.111:/image/debian12,vers=3,nolock panic=60 ipv6.disable=1 rootwait
  initrd /debian12/boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-9-amd64
}
```

The `ip=dhcp` on the kernel command line means that networking has already been set up before `systemd` even starts; and that is why setting the hostname doesn't register with DHCP and DDNS.

Now, to make the system register the hostname on the DDNS server, it has to activate the interface somewhere around `network.target`, but because this is a diskless server, one can't know exactly which NICs are present, so no interfaces have been set up in `/etc/network/interfaces`. One way to address this could be:

```
root@zorn:/etc/network# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto /enp*=eth
iface eth inet dhcp
```

This assumes that NICs are called something that starts with `enp`, which seems to be common ATM, and it works for my simple test system. The hope is that it will also work when there are more than one, and that it will only configure the one that is physically connected.